# Roleplaying a proficient Crab officer - military art references

Tags: l5r, l5r-1e

I've been playing L5R roleplaying game 1st edition, impersonating a Hida bushi.

Hida bushi start off with the Battle skill, which I even raised to 3 over time, and as the story progressed my character is now a somewhat high ranking officer in the Hida army. Please bear in mind that we're talking about 1st edition, so skills can be raised to a maximum of rank 5 (e.g. Akodo Toturi has battle 5), so 3 is quite some skill already.

I'm sometimes having a hard time roleplaying such proficiency in game since I don't know anything at all about military art.

Can anybody point me to basic notions, or a primer about this topic?

**Example**

I once had a friendly dispute with another officer (an NPC) about who of us should have led an upcoming military assault. I engaged him in a game of *Go* and we had a cool scene where we were making references to the upcoming battle and relating them to our moves. The scene came out ok, but I was actually throwing random remarks about the tactics to adopt, while it would have been much cooler if I actually had some knowledge on the subject.
In the end I won the contest, led the assault and managed the battle alright because the rolls came out high, but I'd always like to support the numbers with fitting interpretation.

I remember trying to read Sun Tzu years ago but there was a LOT of philosophy and not much 'technical' stuff (*this* situation is good, *that* situation is bad, deal with it *this* way).

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I guess some will think it is unnecessary to acquire such knowledge in order to pull off good roleplaying, please just assume that it *is* necessary since I'd like to play it that way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a real-world research question requesting a recommendation of a primer on real-world military arts. This would make it [a campaign research question unrelated to RPG expertise](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/are-campaign-research-questions-on-topic-part-two).

Comment: I suggest this question is better handled by asking about your problem and requesting a solution: guidance on how to handle a lack of military art knowledge while playing a character skilled in that. People can provide insight on how you can handle that scenario in L5R, and some answers may provide a military art primer *if it would be helpful*. Presupposing this is a helpful solution makes this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/152515): you have a problem, you have presumed there's a particular solution, and you are asking about that solution instead of the problem.

Comment: This indeed is an XY problem, and while I can see that the general guidelines discourage that (and I can also see why) I'm reading comments in the meta post you linked of users in my same situation. Sometimes you ask an XY problem because you singled 'Y' out.

Comment: About the RPG-specific issue, I'm quoting from your article "but my intention is this: for a given question, would asking it on an RPG board give you a different, better or more specific answer than you could get by asking it elsewhere?" - yes, I'm interested in recommendations from players that roleplayed this kind of character and acquired/made use of military art notions. Asking the same question on a literature board would have a much less specific/precise scope.